# radeditor image manager not showing correctly when upload iis

Tags: radeditor

i have rad editor in my website,and image manager work correctly when browse from VS.but when browse it from Internet Information Service and server image manager dialog not showing correctly and toolbox dose not showing.
how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide a screenshot of the problem?

Have you also enabled the CDN resources of the Image Editor?

Best regards,
Rumen